# How do I get onto the roof of this building?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iii

[image: a]

How do I get onto the roof of this building? It's too high to get there by climbing on top of the truck. Is using Dodo the only way to reach this roof?

This building is located in Portland, near number 30:

[image: a]

Comment: Do you mind giving a location? What district? anything to help locate it?

Comment: screen shot please!

Comment: Map  is added        ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the PlayStation 2 version I was able to get onto that building by driving a car along the elevated subway. Get on at the [Baillie Station](http://gta.wikia.com/Baillie_Station), it's between numbers 21 and 22 on your map. You can drive a car up the stairs there, keep going straight ahead south along the tracks.  When you get to a support holding up the tracks around number 28 on your map, gently turn your car so it's perpendicular to the tracks and hit the gas trying to drive along the support as much as you can. Your car should land on the building you're trying to get onto, but way over on the other side. You'll have to walk on the roof for a fair bit to get to the part of the roof in your picture.

Apparently you don't need a car to get there, you can walk along the tracks and then sprint along the support and jump. The "Liberty Pharmaceuticals" hidden package is located where you're trying to go, so if you can figure out my instructions you can try searching the web for instructions on how to get that package.

Comment: Yeah you're totally right... But after four tries I couldn't get there, failed at the end

Comment: It took me about four tries to do it in car, stopping at the subway support and turning seemed to be the trick. It might be easier on foot, but make sure you're sprinting while jumping. If you're playing the iOS version on a iPad or iPhone the touch controls might make this very difficult.